# Microsoft .NET Framework logo image

Tags: .net

Where can I find a official PNG image of the Microsoft .NET Framework 4.0 suitable for graphic designers (transparent background, reasonable size, etc.)?

Thanks.

Comment: Microsoft icons are copyrighted and Microsoft do not allow the use of them within applications etc - http://www.google.co.uk/url?url=http://www.microsoft.com/about/legal/permissions/%23EEE&rct=j&q=microsoft+icon+copyright&usg=AFQjCNEF9kRzs87Kq_V46tGv-qaRSR8rXQ&sa=X&ei=P1-FT5jmMMa80QXtvqjNBw&ved=0CDIQygQwAA

Comment: The link isn't broken - I just tried it and it's active

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope it helps:

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/news/imagegallery/products/default.aspx

another link from Maxim

http://www.brandsoftheworld.com/logo/microsoft-net-framework